# Smart outlet or timer to auto shut-off after 30 seconds of use

Tags: home-automation

Is there a smart outlet or some special kind of timer that can detect when current starts flowing and turn off after about 30 seconds?

This is intended for a custom hot water circulation system.  I want the pump on a flow switch to turn on for 1 minute or less when flow starts at the water heater's cold water inlet, then turn off and remain off for 30 minutes before becoming available again (regardless of flow switch position).  I thought that cutting power would be the best way to stop the pump after 30-60 seconds because it is no longer needed.

The closest I've seen is this [30-minute auto-shut-off outlet](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01MA6MMMC).

**Edit:** I've decided to use a [Laing pump](https://laing-thermotech.com/plumbing-solar-pumps/autocirc-series-undersink-pump-for-potable-water-systems/) that incorporates temperature shut-off connected through a [timer light switch](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01M4IFLMA).  The Laing pump costs more, but I imagine that it will pay for itself in energy savings in this configuration.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/293889). Maybe [edit] your post to indicate what you're trying to solve in addition to your solution. Someone may come up with a better overall solution instead of a patch to a less desirable solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes - a **time delay relay**, available in various configurations for building industrial controls. Commonly available, but not at Home Cheapo or your local hardware store, most likely.

You would need a 30 second one and a 30 minute one for this described operation.

Or these days you might run the whole operation with an arduino or the like and some external (normal) relays, with the arduino acting both as the "time delay" and perhaps processing other sensor inputs. If you happen to be a coder that would be the logical direction to go, TDRs are somewhat simpler to deal with if you just want to wire things together and not write code.

Answer (score 1):

I used a smart plug and an Alexa routine to turn on the hot water recirc pump, run it for 2 minutes, and then turn off the pump. Hot water can be invoked by voice command or by alarm clock routine. This has worked like a charm for nearly two years now.